# execute a PHP script from Ajax without expecting an answer (and no daemons)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I hope you can help me with this issue:

My sistem runs over Zend Framework, I have installed jQuery in it's latest version. I have an input that receives a file and it makes an Ajax call when changes, and I want that call made in the background, without expecting any response (because that script will send an email when finished). My ajax call is like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $(this).get(0).files[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: 'uploadaddresses.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    async:true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        bootbox.alert("You've made your petition correctly. When finished, an email will be sent to you.")
    },
    error: function(err) {}
});
return false;
```

Although, the call waits for a response (even FireBug shows me that uploadaddresses.php is still executing...). What i'm doing wrong? How should I do it best? I want to avoid using daemons and system calls, because system restrictions...

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: HTTP's "200, OK" is the response you need.

Comment: Any connection over HTTP returns something atleast. Be it a custom return or a HTTP header

Comment: Are you saying that `uploadaddresses.php` runs a long time, and you don't want the ajax request waiting for the php process to finish?

Comment: You could have `uploadaddresses. php` fork a background process to do what it needs to do and immediately return a Http header of 200. That way the Ajax request completes as soon as it is received and you don't have to wait around for the response that it completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting `uploadaddresses.php` to return an HTTP response immediately but continue processing, take a look at `pcntl_fork` in PHP.

Here's the main doc page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Here's a good example that you might want to follow: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php#94338

Comment: My system does not support pcntl_fork :( I can't take this answer, sorry, but I think it was a good approach :)

Comment: What kind of system are you using?

Comment: I'm running Zend Framework over an apache and linux system, but for security reasons I can't activate any module

Comment: You're going to have to work with the system admin on this to get it going. Doing a fork or dropping a job into a scheduler are about the only ways to get this done, but you'll need permissions to do either.

Answer (score 0):

Create a success method for the ajax call and have something like this:

```
console.log("Done");
```

This way you know if is complete and successful but only if you are looking at the dev tools. Unless you specify output it should not continue to run after the call has been made. Maybe you have an error in your PHP code?

EDIT: If you can't get this resolved you may want to post your PHP page as well.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly. I don't want to know if it's complete and successful (or not) because the script will send me an email when finished. I only want to call that script and continue working with other business as my script is running. But thank you anyway :)